# How to extract individual points from the shapely Multipoint data type?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely

I am using shapely2.0; somehow, I can't iterate through individual points in the MULTIPOINT data type in this version.

I wanted to extract and plot individual points from the MULTIPOINT.
The MULTIPOINT is obtained from `line.intersection(circle_boundary)`, where I tried to get the intersection points between line and circle geometry.

Is there any way to access the Individual points in the MULTIPOINT or get the intersecting points as individual shapely Points rather than as MULTIPOINT?

Comment: `multipoint.geoms` is not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MultiPoint geometry object can be `exploded` to become basic Point objects.

Here is a demo code:-

```
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

# Create a geodataframe containing 2 rows, each row has a MultiPoint geometry
s = gpd.GeoSeries(
    [MultiPoint([(0, 0), (1, 1)]), 
     MultiPoint([(2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)])]
)

# Create a new geodataframe from "s" by `s.explode()`
# This geodataframe will have 5 rows, each has simple Point geometry derived from the original geodataframe 
exploded_s = s.explode(index_parts=True)
exploded_s
```

```
0  0    POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
   1    POINT (1.00000 1.00000)
1  0    POINT (2.00000 2.00000)
   1    POINT (3.00000 3.00000)
   2    POINT (4.00000 4.00000)
dtype: geometry
```